# Package for java not being picked up by Chef even when specifying a valid version

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, centos6, java

I am bumping my head due to an error occurring in Chef 13 while trying to spawn a centos/6 image on a vagrant 2.0.2 box.

My task is quite basic: I am trying to install java-openjdk with version 1.8.0 and I am using the *yum_package* as follows:

```
yum_package "java" do
  flush_cache [ :before ]
  arch 'x86_64'
  version "java-1.8.0-openjdk"
  action :install
end
```

And here's the catch:

- If I don't specify the version, I will get java-openjdk 1.5.0.
- When I specify the version, as shown in the code above,  I will get that "no candidate version available for java".
- When I try to state a version >= by doing

  yum_package "java > java-1.8.0-openjdk" do

I will get that many options are available and yum installs java 1.5 since it is the first one it found (which sounds a bit surprising):

```
WARN: yum_package[java >= java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9] matched multiple Provides for java >= java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9 but we can only use the first match: java-1.5.0-gcj. Please use a more specific version.
```

I have even gone to the extent of setting the version to the full name of the file: *java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9.x86_64* which is listed as a valid version once I go inside the vagrant box and do a --show-duplicates from yum:

```
yum search --showduplicates java-1.8.0-openjdk
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hmc.edu
 * epel: mirror.compevo.com
 * extras: mirror.texas3006.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net
===================================================================== N/S Matched: java-1.8.0-openjdk ======================================================================
1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-0.b11.el6_9.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.el6_9.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-3.b16.el6_9.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
```

Even more strangely, once I go inside the box I can easily install java jdk by just running *yum install java*, it will pick up correctly java 1.8.0:

```
root@localhost vagrant]# yum install java
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net
 * epel: ftp.cse.buffalo.edu
 * extras: mirror2.evolution-host.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9 will be installed
```

My question is: is Chef somehow running a different repo to the one I actually have on the machine? Why my cmd within the box shows different java versions to the one Chef is using?

Comment: Have you tried to pass `1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64` or `1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9` as version attribute to java yum resource? Also, try without `el6.x86_64`.

Comment: Yes, still no luck. Have tried all variations of the package name (and even the devel one just to confirm it was not the package). Seems somehow the Chef run for "package" just goes to another repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first we need to rewind a bit and work out what is the package name vs. version. Taking `1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment` as the example, the package name is `java-1.8.0-openjdk` and the version is `1:1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64`, more commonly just given as `1.8.0.121-1.b13`. There is no package actually called `java`, it's a magic-y alias within Yum to do the right thing, but the alias confuses Chef since we query the package info database directly.

So what you want is more like this:

```
package 'java-1.8.0-openjdk' do
  version '1.8.0.121-1.b13'
end
```

or something similar.

Comment: Still not working with the suggestion, tried until the b14, then added piece by piece from the rest.. odd indeed cos it *should* work: 

package 'java-1.8.0-openjdk' do
  version '1.8.0.161-3.b14'
end

Comment: You may need the full `1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9`. I forget how we did that and it's changing in Chef 14 anyway.